# How to make Angular 2 remember scroll position?

Tags: angular, scroll, angular2-router

I'm on page 1, I scroll halfway through the page and then click a link that brings me to page 2 through the Angular router. When I hit the "back" button, I'd like page 1 to be scrolled halfway down, just like it was before I left that page.

What is the easiest way to do that?

Comment: Maybe you could create service in which you will write last scroll position and 'pageId' on component ngDestroy, and next time on ngInit check if there is a scroll positions.

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable solution. I was wondering if Angular had an "out of the box" way to do this through some router config, since it is a default browser behavior that we lose while using the router.

Answer (score 1):

Save to `localStorage` scroll position in `ngOnDestroy()`, and restore it in `ngOnInit()`

Comment: Can anyone explain why this is downvoted?  Is it because the answer is so concise that it is almost unhelpful, or is it because it's a bad way to solve the problem?  I'm trying to solve a similar problem, and I really wish the downvoters had left a comment...

Comment: i did something similar. Just instead of saving it in `localStorage` i wrote a own service.