# Store data in Angular to be remembered the next time the user is on the same page

Tags: javascript, angular, html5-history, angular7

I have an Angular 7 app with plenty of screens (components) that display a grid of records.  I would like to setup these screens so that when a user clicks on a record (visiting another screen) then clicking Back, they see the same filters, sort order, and scroll position.

I have experience doing this in a non-SPA app that uses the same grid library that I'm using in my Angular app (Datatables.net).  I know how to get, set, and stringify the data I need.  In the non-SPA app I simply persisted the data using window.location.replace into the hash portion of the URL.

My question is: what is the best way to approach this in a modern, Angular 6 app?  Possible answers seem to include:

- [HTML 5 History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API)
- The old [window.location API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location), as mentioned above.
- [Angular's Location API](https://angular.io/api/common/Location)
- sessionStorage or [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) as was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42439745/how-to-make-angular-2-remember-scroll-position) but downvoted for reasons I'm not clear on...
- Possibly something via the [Routing & Navigation tooling in Angular](https://angular.io/guide/router) that I've overlooked?

Obviously that's a lot of choices.  What's the best approach?

I found a lot of similar questions asked on SO, but I couldn't find a single one where the answers weren't extremely specific to the use case.

One factor that will affect which answers do/don't work is that I think I'll only want this behavior if the users clicks back but not if they revisit the same screen via the main nav.  So if they click "Orders" in the main nav, it should default to the normal order, no filters, and be scrolled to the top.  Trying to use localStorage, for example, seems easy except that I have no idea how I'd tell if a user clicked the main nav or clicked Back.

Comment: ngrx/store would be best option to store and use it across application

Comment: using service is also one good option by setting and getting value

Comment: @NagaSaiA What value would using a service have over just using SessionStorage? I can't think of any.